# Why the error "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag" happens only on some devices?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm getting a crash report on Firebase with the message

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

This error occurs on a Samsung GT-I9500 with Android 19. I can't reproduce the error o my Google Pixel with Android Oreo (27).

I know how to set the flag, but I'm curious to know why this error occurs only on some versions of Android.

Here's how I'm starting the Activity:

```
    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm curious to know why this error occurs only on some versions of Android.

Because of a bug. See [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36520749) and [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64069975).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I was pretty confused about this issue too.